# Yii framework: migrations doesn't create/drop tables

Tags: php, database, web, yii, database-migration

Tried to use Yii migrations to drop one table and to create 2 another. 
Here is code:

```
    <?php

class m130919_095159_create_offer_tables extends CDbMigration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->getDbConnection()->createCommand()->dropTable('offer');

        $this->createTable('settings', array(
            'id' => 'pk',
            'offer_id' => 'integer NOT NULL',
            'system_id' => 'integer NULL',  
            'site_title' => 'varchar(255) NULL',
            'index_number' => 'integer NULL',  
            'coupon_token' => 'varchar(255) NULL',
            'facebook_app_id' => 'varchar(255) NULL',
            'facebook_app_secret' => 'varchar(255) NULL',
        ));

        $this->createTable('content', array(
            'id' => 'pk',
            'offer_id' => 'integer NOT NULL',
            'created' => 'datetime NOT NULL',
            'modified' => 'datetime NOT NULL',
            'status' => 'integer NOT NULL',
            'title_uz' => 'varchar(255) NULL',
            'title_ru' => 'varchar(255) NULL',
            'description_uz' => 'text NULL',
            'description_ru' => 'text NULL', 
        ));
    }

    public function down()
    {
        echo "m130919_095159_create_offer_tables does not support migration down.\n";
        return false;
    }
}
```

After i executed command `php yiic.php migrate` and get answer `migrated up successfully`. Problem is sql commands haven't been executed. Table hasen't dropped, another tables doesn't created. No changes in database. Can't find out reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u are using migrations in a wrong way. The right approach is whatever thing u r doing in up function just try to do the opposite in the down function.

suppose here you are dropping one table and creating two table in the up function then u should write codes in down function

create table code for the table which u r dropping in up and drop table code for the two tables that u r creating in up

first of all check your database configuration in console.php

```
public function up() {
  $this->dropTable('offer');
  $this->createTable('settings', array(
      'id' => 'pk',
      'offer_id' => 'integer NOT NULL',
      'system_id' => 'integer NULL',  
      'site_title' => 'varchar(255) NULL',
      'index_number' => 'integer NULL',  
      'coupon_token' => 'varchar(255) NULL',
      'facebook_app_id' => 'varchar(255) NULL',
      'facebook_app_secret' => 'varchar(255) NULL',
  ));
   $this->createTable('content', array(
      'id' => 'pk',
      'offer_id' => 'integer NOT NULL',
      'created' => 'datetime NOT NULL',
      'modified' => 'datetime NOT NULL',
      'status' => 'integer NOT NULL',
      'title_uz' => 'varchar(255) NULL',
      'title_ru' => 'varchar(255) NULL',
      'description_uz' => 'text NULL',
      'description_ru' => 'text NULL', 
  ));
}

public function down(){
  $this->createTable('offer', array(
    //attributes for offer table
  ));
  $this->dropTable('settings');
  $this->dropTable('content');
}
```

Comment: Yes, u r right, problem was db configuration in console.php. Thanx a lot, Neophile

Comment: Duck! Spent 30 minutes looking at magic and no effect at my mysqldb when it turned out that it writes to  sql db.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your database correctly on both main.php and console.php under config directory. If you are using MySQL uncomment that section and comment testdrive.db under sqlite.